# Pseudo Class Last Child

Tags: css, menu

I'm trying to achieve the separator effect using border-right on my menu.
Here's my css code

```
ul.navigation li a {
text-decoration:none;
float:left;
width:252px;
height:50px;
display:block;
background-color:#ccc;
text-align:center;
line-height:45px;
color:#000;
position:relative;
border-right:1px solid #333;
}

ul.navigation li a:last-child {
border:none;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried `border-left` and `:first-child` too.

Comment: You seem very confused here. You say last child in the title but use `:first-child` in your code, and you're tagging your question with all the CSS versions...

Comment: Which browsers? Not every browser supports `:first-child`.

Comment: @BoltClock I need to talk with you, can you get me on chat?

Comment: :first-child is more widely supported, so to achieve what you are trying to do, I usually add a left border and set border: none on :first-child

Comment: Edited my question, please check again, I'm using Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 m (Latest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am thinking you mean to do this

```
ul.navigation li:first-child a
```

Because every `a` is the first child of its parent `li`. You mean the `a` inside the first li item. :)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Hoping to be pros like you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS snippet is full of bad practices.

Below is an example of how you should style it and how you can add a separator between each list item.

```
.navigation { overflow: hidden; }    /* Explanation 1 */
.navigation li { float: left; }

.navigation li + li {                /* Explanation 2 */
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
}

.navigation li a {
    display: block;
    width: 252px;                    /* Explanation 3 */
    padding: 5px 0;                  /* Explanation 4 */

    background-color:#ccc;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;            
}
```

1. Float containment: [read this article](http://colinaarts.com/articles/float-containment/).
2. Here I answer your question: applies a border left from the 2nd li to the last one, using the adiacent sibling selector `+`.
3. Are you sure you want to have a fixed width?
4. No fixed height and line-height to vertically align the text. line-height doen't need a unit by the way. [Read this article](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200603/css_lineheight_does_not_need_a_unit/).

   Here is a live example: http://dabblet.com/gist/4968063

Comment: I learned a lot from this too. I have a lot of bad practices in coding css and html. Is there a site that will teach on how to remove bad practices?  Also, is "ul.navigation li:first-child a" a bad practice? and should i start using the adjacent sibling selector +.

Comment: I am glad to help. 

`ul.navigation li:first-child a` is not a bad practice per se and it is just fine. 

I would suggest you to join the #css support channel on Freenode http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=css there is plenty of people ready to help you.